# iPython notebook won't open some files

Tags: ipython, tornado, jupyter-notebook

I have a git folder with several ipython notebook files in it. I've just got a new comp and installed ipython. When I open some files, it works fine, others, however, display this error:
Error loading notebook, bad request.

The log looks like:

2014-07-16 00:20:11.523 [NotebookApp] WARNING | Unreadable Notebook: /nas-6000/wclab/Ahmed/Notebook/01 - Boundary Layer.ipynb [Errno 5] Input/output error

WARNING:tornado.access:400 GET /api/notebooks/01%20-%20Boundary%20Layer.ipynb?_=1405434011080 (127.0.0.1) 3.00ms referer=linktofile

The read/write and owner permissions are the same for each of the files. The files open fine on my other computers, it's just this new one. Any ideas?

Cheers,
James

Comment: Show us all the log. And are you sure all ipython notebook dependencies are up-to-date? (like tornado)

Comment: The ipynb files are just JSON, so you should be able to open them with any text editor, although output images etc. will be encoded. Can you try opening the notebook using vim/emacs in readonly mode for example?

Answer (score 2):

Errno 5 is a low level error usually reported when your disk has bad sectors.

I don't think the error is related to the file or ipython, check your disk with an appropriate tool (fsck if you are using Linux).

Comment: If you run `git status` you should also have some feedback if git can't read the file as I think.